# Unable to find metadata to parse GlideModules

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide in my project, and it works perfect.
The problem is that from time to time i am getting a crash in Fabric (Crashlytics).
The crash cause: Unable to find metadata to parse GlideModules.
It happens in strange devices like "Affordable -A101".
I think it can not find the name of the package, but i don't know why it happens and how to solve it.

**Log**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.infibond.base.BaseApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find metadata to parse GlideModules
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4544)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find metadata to parse GlideModules
       at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parse(ManifestParser.java:35)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:149)
       at com.infibond.base.BaseApplication.initGlide(BaseApplication.java:165)
       at com.infibond.base.BaseApplication.onCreate(BaseApplication.java:127)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4541)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

**ApplicationBase:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (InfiLogger.LOGGING.isLogEnabled(InfiLogger.LOGGING.LOG_FLAG_LIFECYCLE)) {
            InfiLogger.i(InfiLogger.LOGGING.TAG_LIFECYCLE, getClass().getSimpleName() + " onCreate()");
        }

        initCrashlytics();
        initCustomFontsLib();
        sInstance = (BaseApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
        sMainAppHandler = new Handler();

        // print current SHA code for package
        //JavaUtils.printSHACodesForPackage(getPackageName());

        // update app internet connectivity status
        InfiConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.updateConnectivity();

        AdobeCSDKFoundation.initializeCSDKFoundation(getApplicationContext());

        saveCurrentLocale();

        DBManager.initializeActiveAndroid(this);

        //initNewRelic();

        handleSSLHandshake();

        initGlide();
    }

    private void initGlide() {
        Glide.get(this).setMemoryCategory(MemoryCategory.HIGH);
    }
```